# Zero row in Identity 1,1 Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-performance, identity-column

I’m in the process of cleaning up an old database. I have a table, User, with Identity 1,1 set for the User.SequenceNumber column which is used as the foreign key in many tables as the users ID number. Another table, UserNotes, had many records added erroneously over the past years and the UserNotes.UserID is zero. My initial thoughts were to add a User.SequenceNumber of zero with the User.UserName of ‘Unknown’ to restore the foreign key constraint between User.SequenceNumber and UserNotes.UserID. I have been able to successfully do this in the test area with a few records.

My concern is, when I add the ‘zero’ row, will it start causing problems in my 5 million plus database that has approximately 6 reads plus 4 records saved per minute?  I found where people have problems with the database doing this when they don’t want it to happen but not where someone wanted to do this intentionally.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: With the identity set to begin with 1, will having a zero row cause problems when I add it to the production table described above? It worked OK in the five row test table but if this causes problems I'll have a much larger problem later on.

Comment: I added the 0 column and it has been working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a 0 into a column defined as `IDENTITY(1,1)` should be fine as far as the database is concerned, because you would be inserting a value outside the range allocated for automatically generated values (which, assuming `int`, is `[1..2,147,483,647]`), meaning that your arbitrary value would not interfere with automatic value generation.

This *could* affect your application, although not very likely. For instance, if your application sees a 0 reference as a special value not because it is 0 but because of the absence of rows with `SequenceNumber = 0` in `User`, that logic would be broken with the addition of the 0 row.

Alternatively, you could just replace all the zeros in `UserNotes.UserID` with NULLs. That would seem to me a more natural way to designate an "unknown" reference. On the other hand, it would also seem to me more likely to affect the application, and possibly to a greater extent too – particularly if the application is already set to work with zeros as special reference values *and* designed in a way so as to immediately distinguish between a 0 and a NULL when reading the results of a query.

Either way, there is a bigger issue you seem to be facing here. The fact that `UserNotes.UserID` has been allowed to contain non-existing references of 0, a value not found in the `User.SequenceNumber` column, implies that `UserNotes.UserID` is not *formally* defined as a foreign key. When there is no formal foreign key/primary key relationship, there is no referential integrity either (from the database's stand point anyway), and your `UserNotes` table is prone to getting non-existent references even after the clean-up you are carrying out.

You should really consider establishing the formal relationship between the tables at the database level. That may require additional changes to the application (depending on how it is designed), but it would be a justified time/effort investment and might spare you some headache in the future.

Comment: Thank you, this project was my first time to work in .net and my first time with SQL. The database was inherited but the web code was new. The reason for the update was to fix all of the DB problems such as the lack of referential integrity. Adding the 0 User.SequenceNumber allowed me to easily establish referential integrity between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to break the Identity property.

I think you're right to be concerned that an artificial change could have side effects.  But I think the application-side ones are the concern... what else does your application do with the record that you haven't considered.

If the zero row is unique and you don't have any other constraints on the column, you can insert the row.